# Navigation Bar Large Title transition delegate

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, large-title, preferslargetitles

I have enabled `Large Title` in my navigation bar with automatic `Display Mode`, so that it shrinks when user scrolls. Is there a way to get notified when this transition happens? I didn't found any delegate method for this. I have a `Right Bar Button Item` with long label which I'd like to hide when Large Title gets shrunk so that the title is perfectly centered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there's no delegate nor any other official way to be notified about this. So my workaround is using `ScrollViewDelegate`:

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if let height = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height, height == 44 {
            // handle small title
        }
        else {
            // handle large title
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work on iPad as the height of navbar is different, but that's intended in my case.

Also keep in mind that `scrollViewDidScroll` gets called XX times for a single small scroll, so before doing any updates, check they haven't been done already.

Comment: You could check the same thing inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. It is being called a little bit less often than `scrollViewDidScroll`.

Comment: Is there a better way to not hardcode 44?